# Allow LaTeX math notation on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request

Some Stack Exchange sites (Computer Science) allow using [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) notation for equations, such as $O(n^2)$.

I would find it useful to have this feature also on Stack Overflow, for example when discussing the complexity of algorithms.

Since the feature is already available on some Stack Exchange sites, it should be easy to allow it on other sites, such as Stack Overflow.

Or are there other reasons why this is not supported?

Comment: Just one out of many dupes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30559

Comment: Agreed. Weird that it didn't show any of the duplicates when I searched (superficially, I admit).